# stop jquery animate after seeing the last image

Tags: jquery

How can I make the div "con" stop when the last picture appear at the screen ?

meaning I want the animation to stop working when I see the last image in the right

thank you

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVLWRg

html

```
<div class="con">
  <div class="conSingle">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/cjgKmvp.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="conSingle">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/cjgKmvp.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="conSingle">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/cjgKmvp.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="conSingle">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/cjgKmvp.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="conSingle">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/cjgKmvp.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(".con").click(function() {
       $(this).animate({right:"+=100"},1000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var last = $(".conSingle:last"), offsetRight;
    $(".con").click(function() {
        if(!$(this).is(":animated")){
            offsetRight = $(window).width() - (last.offset().left + last.width());
            if(offsetRight !== 0){
                if(offsetRight + 100 < 0){
                    $(this).animate({left:"-=100"},500);
                }else{
                    $(this).animate({left:"-="+(-offsetRight)},500);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    $('button').click(function(){
        if(!$(".con").is(":animated")){
            $(".con").animate({left:"0"},500);
        }
    });
});
```

It check the `offset right` of `.con` element, and when this `offset` is higher than `0`, then stop the animation.

**DEMO:** https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/wd3cky5u/2/

Comment: Hi, what about the oposit ? if I want to add a button for going back ! I tried to but couldn't. please help

Comment: I update my answer with a [new demo](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/wd3cky5u/2/). Enjoy it!

Comment: Thank you very much .. god knows how much time I wasted for this. Againe thank you very very much sir